# Solution to diffusion equation in cylindrical coordinates using FiPy not correct

Tags: python, differential-equations, fipy, cylindrical

The steady-state solution to a diffusion equation in cylindrical geometry using FiPy is rather different from the solution obtained from another software, eg., Mathematica.

The equation is:

$0 = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{r}{T^{1/2}}\frac{dT}{dr}\right) + cte*T^{3/2}$

which means that, by using a CylindricalGrid1D mesh, we can write the equation as:

```
mesh = CylindricalGrid1D(nr=100, dr=0.01, origin=0.0)
T = CellVariable(name='temperature', mesh=mesh, hasOld=True)
r = mesh.cellCenters()

#BC's
T.constrain(0., mesh.facesRight)
T.faceGrad.constrain(0.,mesh.facesLeft)

#initial temperature profile
T.setValue( 1-r**2)

eq = 0 == DiffusionTerm( coeff=T**(-1/2), var=T) + 20*ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=T**(1/2), var=T)

viewer = Viewer(vars=T)
eq.solve()

viewer.plot()
raw_input(" Press <enter> to proceed...")
```

In here I have set cte=20, but the problem remains whatever this value is. I get the solution on the left whereas the solution given by Mathematica is the one on the right:

[plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8oHY.jpg)

I then tried to sweep as recommended for such non-linear equation like this. So instead of `eq.solve()`, I did:

```
current_residual = 1.0e100
desired_residual = 1e-5

while current_residual > desired_residual:

    current_residual = eq.sweep()
    T.updateOld()
```

But I get the error:

```
/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/linearLUSolver.py:66: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  error0 = numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum((L * x - b)**2))
/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/linearLUSolver.py:71: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  if (numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum(errorVector**2)) / error0)  <= self.tolerance:
/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/linearLUSolver.py:71: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if (numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum(errorVector**2)) / error0)  <= self.tolerance:
/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/tools/numerix.py:966: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return sqrt(add.reduce(arr**2))
/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/linearLUSolver.py:58: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  b = b * (1 / maxdiag)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 26, in <module>
    current_residual = eq.sweep()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/terms/term.py", line 254, in sweep
    solver._solve()
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/scipySolver.py", line 61, in _solve
    self.var[:] = numerix.reshape(self._solve_(self.matrix, self.var.ravel(), numerix.array(self.RHSvector)), self.var.shape)   
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/solvers/scipy/linearLUSolver.py", line 64, in _solve_
    permc_spec=3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 257, in splu
    ilu=False, options=_options)
RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular
```

Finally, I re-wrote the initial equation in an equivalente form by using the variable V=T^{1/2}. It's easy to see that with V the equation becomes

$0 = \frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dV}{dr}\right) + \frac{cte}{2}V^3$

So I then used the code:

```
mesh = CylindricalGrid1D(nr=100, dr=0.01, origin=0.0)
V = CellVariable(name='V', mesh=mesh, hasOld = True)
r = mesh.cellCenters()

#BC's
V.constrain(0., mesh.facesRight)
V.faceGrad.constrain(0.,mesh.facesLeft)

#initial V profile
V.setValue( 1-r**2)

eqV = 0 == DiffusionTerm( coeff=1., var=V) + 20*0.5*ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=V*V, var=V)

T = V*V
viewer = Viewer(vars=T)

eqV.solve()

viewer.plot()
raw_input(" Press <enter> to proceed...")
```

and the profile obtained is quite similar, but the values in the y-axis are not the same either from the first FiPy solution or Mathematica one! Sweeping is giving the same error as before.

Comment: Please provide a complete working example, including your mesh definition and your initialization of `T`

Comment: @jeguyer I've just added that to initial post.

Comment: This code still doesn't run. What's `T0`? What's `Ta`? How did you declare `r`? Please provide a complete working example.

Comment: @jeguyer sorry about that. Now it's completely working. I also changed the final part of the question with some "progress" I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced this problem has any solution other than T = 0. Further, that solution seems to be unstable against different values of the initial condition and/or of `cte`. That instability is not altogether surprising given that the equation in `T` form would have an infinite diffusivity when T = 0.

I suspect that Mathematica is doing roughly what FiPy is doing in your first set of figures, which is to show the first sweep of this non-linear problem. It's not the answer;  just the first guess. I don't know anything about solving PDEs with Mma, though, either analytically or numerically.

The plot after one sweep after your `V` solution looks different, btw, because you didn't adjust the initial condition. It should be:

```
V.setValue( numerix.sqrt(1-r**2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll put some more thought on it, and if I find out that there should be other solution than the trivial one, I will make a comment here later

Comment: Coming back to this, why is it that when adding the transient term to this equation, I cannot see the profile evolving to T(x)=0? Indeed, when I add that term, I get the error `All-NaN axis encountered`, which I suspect is due to the T^{-1/2} term. How would one circumvent this? I though that one way would be by setting the origin of the mesh slightly deviated from zero, but I get the same error.

Comment: I don't definitively know the answer. As I said before, `T=0` seems to be an unstable solution. If the initial condition is of small enough magnitude, or if `cte` is of small enough magnitude, then `T=0` is obtained in steady-state. It's possible that adding a `TransientTerm` for a relaxation solution would also find `T=0` if the time step were small enough.